Flag on own comment
Can I somehow attract mod's attention to my own comment on an answer for validity? I'm not sure if my comment is complete or not.
Example: Where is coinbase transaction after a hacker successfully performs >50% attack?

My usual procedure would be to only tackle topics that I feel reasonably sure about. However, it is acceptable to take a question as a point to start your own research in order to answer it. A lot of questions can be answered to the asker's satisfaction when one has a bit of background knowledge and knows where to find the remaining bits and pieces.
Also, if the question is of any interest, somebody else will also read it, or there will be additional answers to create a more comprehensive picture. Gross mistakes are the easiest to get corrected that way, they are usually pointed out quickly. Harder are half-truths and vagueness, but those can be corrected by further queries from the asker or other interested parties, as well as additional answers improving on that points.
Please do not produce content and then flag it for "moderator attention" in order to get it proofread, if everyone were to do that we'd have our own scalability challenge. ;)
However, feel free to request help in chat to improve your question.
